# Missing Export Model Button

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

[image: Vertex AI model Registry View]

Tutorials suggest that we can exporet our model by clicking a button that should be beside VIEW DATASET in the Image ^^

https://youtu.be/aNWCzyCK4Us?t=397

^^ tutorial that shows export button.

I'm not sure if the issue is permissions or that the ui has changed since they wrote the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

When you train the dataset, try to select AutoML Edge as the algorithm (instead of Cloud). That setting should enable later exporting of the created model.